# Reference messages and access attachments

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I am writing a program to track the current status of projects.

The users would like to save relevant documents to the current project.  I can do this for files that are residing in a folder with FileSaveDialog.  However, many times the file is an e-mail message or an attachment to a message.  I would like to grab this directly from Outlook and either save the message as an MSG or save the attachment.

I have code like below to reference Outlook messages from VB.NET but I can't figure out how to reference an entire message to save as msg or attachment filename.

```
Dim objOutlook As Outlook._Application
objOutlook = New Outlook.Application()
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection = objOutlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection
Dim iCount As Int16 = objSelection.Count
For i = iCount To 1 Step -1
    Console.WriteLine(objSelection.Item(i).Subject)
    Console.WriteLine(objSelection.Item(i).Attachments)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Outlook Object Library for this.
An example on how to download an attachment from an unread mail:

```
Private Sub ThisAddIn_NewMail() Handles Application.NewMail
Dim inBox As Outlook.MAPIFolder = Me.Application.ActiveExplorer() _
    .Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook. _
    OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
Dim inBoxItems As Outlook.Items = inBox.Items
Dim newEmail As Outlook.MailItem
inBoxItems = inBoxItems.Restrict("[Unread] = true")
Try 
    For Each collectionItem As Object In inBoxItems
        newEmail = TryCast(collectionItem, Outlook.MailItem)
        If newEmail IsNot Nothing Then 
            If newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then 
                For i As Integer = 1 To newEmail.Attachments.Count
                    Dim saveAttachment As Outlook.Attachment = _
                        newEmail.Attachments(i)
                    newEmail.Attachments(i).SaveAsFile _
                        ("C:\TestFileSave\" & (newEmail _
                        .Attachments(i).FileName))
                Next i
            End If 
        End If 
    Next collectionItem
Catch ex As Exception
    If Left(ex.Message, 11) = "Cannot save" Then
        MsgBox("Create Folder C:\TestFileSave")
    End If 
End Try
```

End Sub

Good luck!

[Source: msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268754.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem as you on saving an e-mail message I ended up with the following solution:

```
Sub SaveEmail()
   'Save e-mail from Outlook
   Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
   Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
   Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
   Dim strFile As String

   'Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
   objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

   'Get the collection of selected objects.
   objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

   'Set the target folder
   Dim FilePath1 as String
   FilePath1 = "C:\tmp\"

   'Save each selected e-mail to disk
   For Each objMsg In objSelection
      'Save attachment before deleting from item.
      'Get the file name using "objMsg.Subject" and remove special characters.
      strFile = Regex.Replace(objMsg.Subject, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_ -]", "-",_ 
      RegexOptions.Compiled)

      'Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
      strFile = FilePath1 & strFile & ".msg"

      'Save the attachment as a file.
      objMsg.SaveAs(strFile, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG)
   Next
End Sub
```

For a bit of input on the regex.replace function please see the following links:

https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_String_